Slow query performance while using JPQL and Spring with optional parameters
I reached a very weird problem (IMO). I'm in the development of a project that uses some very old (and not at all optimized) tables, and we were using Spring with Hibernate to do the heavy work of the queries to the BBDD, but we reached an impasse when accessing one of our heaviest tables (bunch of relations between other tables and so on) since the SQL that Spring was trying to generate was so big and not at all fast.
SO! I started using JPQL to still get some of the power that comes with the framework and with the help of some post here and there I found this solution for optional parameters:
@Query("SELECT e FROM Example e LEFT JOIN e.houses ho " +
       "WHERE " +
       "(:someValue1 IS NULL OR e.someValue1 = someValue1) AND " +
       "(:someValue2 IS NULL OR e.someValue2 = someValue2) AND " +
       "(:someValue3 IS NULL OR e.someValue3 = someValue3)")

Of course accessing a LOT more properties and with a bunch of specific filters, but that's not the point, it was just a glorified long version of the example. So when I used that query, no matter the amount of parameters I activated (or not), if I take the SQL generated from Hibernate and run it against our BD, the queries respond really fast (need!) BUT whenever I try to use the query from my application it goes slow, but REALLY SLOW. We're talking from ~1s - to 14+ seconds.
I already figured out it's the OR clause fault (after a bunch of testing and going back and forward), because if I erase them and just start passing the parameters that are going to be used, it starts being fast again.
Can anyone give me an explanation? I just want to understand it.
Thanks in advance!

Are you sure you pass exact same parameters when you run sql script?

Hi! Yes I'm. Been trying everything for a week

You need to run it in profiler then. Also check you use same connection string. Maybe there are some parameters in it that change performance.

The most likely reason for the huge difference in query execution time is the amount of data being retrieved. In one case, you load all the data from the table, so the query is slow. In the other case, you load the data in parts, just as much as fits on the screen, so the query is fast.
